# Ajax não envia dados para o php!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

O código no Ajax funciona perfeitamente mas os dados não são enviados para o php!
Aonde estou errando?

AJAX.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AJAX.js"></script>
        <style>
            .comments{
                margin-left:400px;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cadastro"> 
            <form id="form-msg"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <p>
                        <span>Digite seu comentário:</span>
                        <input type="textbox" id="mensagem">
                        <button type="button"> Clique  </button>
                    </p>  

                </fieldset>
            </form>   
        </div>     
            <p>Comentários</p>
            <span id="aqui"></span>     
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

AJAX_ACTION.php

```php
<?php


$mensagem = $_REQUEST['mensagem'];
echo $mensagem;
```

AJAX.js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("button").click(function(){              
        var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val()
        if (mensagem == ''){
            alert("Comentário não pode ser vazio")
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({        
                type: 'POST',
                url: "AJAX_ACTION.php",
                data: {
                    mensagem: mensagem,


                },   
                dataType: "json",
                success: 
                    $("#aqui").append("<br>").append(mensagem),
                done:
                    $("#mensagem").val(''), 

            });                   
        }   
    });     
});
```

Comment: Como vc sabe que não está enviando?

Comment: Já tentei alterar o url do Ajax para "AJAX.php" e colocar o código do php lá, mesmo assim nada ocorre, o echo $mensagem nunca imprime nada.

Comment: vou reorganizar tudo pra vc. E depois vc readapta para seu projeto ok?

Comment: OK! Na verdade é só mais um teste mesmo...

Comment: @PedroHenrique verifique se deu certo,

Comment: O problema é que você especificou que a resposta seria um JSON e seu php retorna uma string sem o formato JSON que é recusada. Coloque `dataType: "text"` que aceita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o callback do `success`, e em vez de `done`, use `complete`. O callback do `complete` é executado após a passar pelo callback do `success`:

```
,success: function(response){
   // faz algo aqui se deu tudo certo
}
,complete: function(){
   // faz algo aqui se deu tudo certo ou não
}
```

Repare que a variável `response` (você pode usar o nome que quiser) é o que retorna do backend (no seu exemplo, o `echo $mensagem;` do PHP).

Retire a opção `dataType: "json",` senão o `success` não será executado caso o retorno não seja um JSON válido.

Comment: É realmente necessário usar o function() e receber o valor como argumento nesses casos?

Comment: Se ele quiser receber uma resposta do servidor, é necessário sim.

Comment: Então sem o `echo`  do meu php neste caso o argumento `mensagem` não terá valor no `success`? Pensava que o valor desta variável era relacionado ao javascript apenas. Agora resolvido então.

Comment: A variável `mensagem` tem o valor que vem de `var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val()`. Até aí tudo ok. Porém, se vc deseja receber algum dado do PHP, é preciso usar a `function()` (callback).

Answer (score 1):

Pedro, primeiro coloquei tudo em letras minúsculas para organização.
Depois alterei sua função de `onClick` para `submit` colocando este `type` no seu `button`.

Segue index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX</title>

        <style>
            .comments{
                margin-left:400px;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cadastro"> 
            <form id="form-msg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <p>
                        <span>Digite seu comentário:</span>
                        <input type="textbox" id="mensagem">
                        <button type="submit" id="enviar"> Clique  </button>
                    </p> 
                </fieldset>
            </form>   
        </div>     
            <p>Comentários</p>
            <span id="aqui"></span>     
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) Outra alteração que eu realizei foi acrescentar seu ajax.js abaixo do seu formulário:

ajax.js

```
$('#form-msg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val()
    if (mensagem == ''){
        alert("Comentário não pode ser vazio")
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_action.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'mensagem': $('#mensagem').val()                
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#aqui").append("<br>").append(data),

            $("#mensagem").val('')                                                                      
        });
    }
});
```

3) ajax_action.php:

```
<?php
    $mensagem = $_REQUEST['mensagem'];
        echo 'SEU ARQUIVO PHP: ' . $mensagem;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: +1, porém eu peço que coloque `dataType: 'text'`, mesmo que hoje o retorno em html` não sofra validação um dia poderá vir a sofrer, assim como hoje é  feito com JSON, o que no futuro poderia vir a invalidar sua resposta.

Comment: Leandro, a variável passou para o php mas agora não está executando o "done" do ajax. Substitui por success e não adiantou também.

Comment: @PedroHenrique O que vc está esperando do .done?

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo resolvido a questão na resposta abaixo, obrigado.