# Refresh sem perder dados, é possível?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

O código abaixo permite que o usuário insira um comentário que é retornado pelo callback do ajax para a mesma página.
Existe uma maneira via javascript ou php que ao **atualizar** a página os comentários inseridos não são perdidos?

AJAX.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX</title>

        <style>
            .comments{
                margin-left:400px;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cadastro"> 
            <form id="form-msg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <p>
                        <span>Digite seu comentário:</span>
                        <input type="textbox" id="mensagem">
                        <button type="submit" id="enviar"> Clique  </button>
                    </p> 
                </fieldset>
            </form>   
        </div>     
            <p>Comentários</p>
            <span id="aqui"></span>     
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

AJAX_ACTION.php

```php
<?php

$mensagem = $_REQUEST['mensagem'];

echo "Vem do callback: " . $mensagem;
```

AJAX.js

```js
$('#form-msg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val()
    if (mensagem == ''){
        alert("Comentário não pode ser vazio")
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_action.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                'mensagem': $('#mensagem').val()                
            },
            success:  function(mensagem){
                $("#aqui").append("<br>").css("color", "red").append(mensagem)
            },              
            complete:  function(){
                $("#mensagem").val('')
            },             
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Você está usando algum tipo de banco de dados para persistir as informações?

Comment: Você precisará persistir estas informações em algum lugar como um banco de dados, por exemplo.

Comment: Então, sem o banco de dados sem jeito?

Comment: Pedro tente explicar MELHOR o que vc precisa, pois já tivemos esta pergunta realizada no site.

Comment: Com JS você usar um cookie. Pesquise por localStorage.

Comment: Existe uma maneira via javascript ou php que ao atualizar a página os comentários inseridos não são perdidos?
Você não está usando banco de dados para isto?

Comment: @PedroHenrique, é até possível fazer sem banco de dados, usando local storage ou então algum cookie mas seria visível apenas para a pessoa que enviou o comentário... outra forma seria você escrever esses comentários em algum lugar de alguma outra forma, como em um arquivo de texto no hd. Porém é muito mais trabalhoso e não faz o menor sentido numa aplicação real pois os bancos de dados estão ai pra isso... Sem armazenar a informação em algum lugar, não dá pra recuperá-la..

Comment: Dem uma olhada no layout do HTML. O @PedroHenrique quer que os comentários fiquem anexados a página tal qual comentários em blog. Pedro, se fo isso, só com php e banco de dados.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ajax não envia dados para o php!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/405527/ajax-n%c3%a3o-envia-dados-para-o-php)

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo não creio que se trata de uma duplicata, o código das perguntas é o mesmo mas a pergunta em si é diferente. Desejo saber se os comentários inseridos no html via javascript poderiam permanecer ali mesmo ao atualizar a página, sem uso de banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Para quem possa interessar, segue a forma de armazenar os comentários em local storage do navegador e não perde-los com um simples refresh na página. Inclusive o local storage permite que os dados fiquem salvos mesmo após fechar o navegador.

No arquivo AJAX.js inserimos a função para carregar as informações (comentários) com um loop. Também inserimos um `try catch`para alertar o usuário caso seu navegador não permita armazenamento de dados.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        if(window.localStorage){
            if(localStorage.getItem(1) !== null){
                for (var i = 1; i <= localStorage.length; i++) {               
                    $("#aqui").append("<br>").append(localStorage.getItem(i))
                    console.log(localStorage.length)
                }  

            }       
        } 
    } catch(e) {
        alert("O seu navegador não permite salvar dados localmente, isso pode afetar a sua experiência com o site!");
    }   
});
```

No mesmo arquivo criamos uma variável global para armazenar o valor do último índice de armazenamento pois no Ajax necessitaremos sempre do último índice + 1 na inserção no local storage.

```js
var key = 0;
```

Finalmente no Ajax, na tratativa success recebemos os comentários que é variável `mensagem` e o adicionamos no último índice +1

```js
$('#form-msg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val()
    if (mensagem == ''){
        alert("Comentário não pode ser vazio")
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_action.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                'mensagem': $('#mensagem').val()                
            },
            success:  function(mensagem){
                $("#aqui").append("<br>").append(mensagem);
                //Inserção no local storage
                key++;
                localStorage.setItem(key, mensagem);                

            },              
            complete:  function(){
                $("#mensagem").val('')
            },           
        });      
    }
});
```

Lembrando que o conteúdo existente na suab local storage pode ser visualizado no caso do Chrome em Devtools > Application > Storage > Local Storage